# What is the noise electrical appliances / lights make before the power goes out during a blackout?

Tags: physics

I have no prior EE experience, but I am curious about why there is a strange noise when a blackout occurs. It makes a high pitched noise right before the lights fade out? What causes incandescent lights to make the noise while the lights are fading out?

Comment: Can you describe the noise ? Is it heard everywhere, or only your home / office / specific place ?

Comment: That's the sound of silence.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about non EE related strange noises.

Comment: Angelina, it's because the electronics are designed to work *normally* at regular voltage. When the mains power sags and cuts out, everything from TV's to lights tries to keep going, modifying their operation to suit the falling power. Eventually it shuts off. When powering on, there is a large surge as everything tries to draw gobs of power, which can even make wires vibrate and shake, leading to strange noises.

Comment: I am voting against closing this. It is an EE question after all. You may not have experienced blackouts. I have experienced many. Some of them have a slow failure where before the lights go out they go dim, and there might be some fluctuation. And that can be associated with some buzzing or humming noise. The EE question is, what kind of fluctuation / frequency / amplitude can get an incandescent light bulb to buzz or hum? And how about the new energy saving light bulbs?

Comment: Even if it actually were "the sound of slience", there would still be an EE question here, which is "what was the noise that the electrical appliances / lights were making _before_ the power went out, and why?"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because neither the noise nor the circumstances where it occurs are described with sufficient detail to make a specific answer possible.  Not even the type of "lights" has been specified.  Traditional domestic incandescent lamps do not make noise when switched off or undervolted.  Alternate technologies have a variety of noise making behavior, especially in conditions of misoperation, but the necessary specifics are entirely missing.

Comment: maybe they are scared of the dark.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow I edited the question to make it more specific. Is this question more acceptable? Thanks :)